# Inject namespace in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

Is it possible to inject a namespace into an XSLT document so that (for instance) the value of a string is used to specify a namespace? I know that it is similarly possible to declare attributes and elements (for instance) using the `<xsl:attribute/>` and `<xsl:element/>` constructs, respectively. Is there a similar construct for namespaces?
The reason why I ask for this is that I want to construct an XSLT transformation for constructing an XML request used across a number of vendors that accepts the same XML structure (except that they apply different namespaces).
I use the Saxon XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 and later there is `xsl:namespace` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#creating-namespace-nodes) of course, I am not sure however it will help to deal with input from different namespaces as, like `xsl:element`, it creates result nodes. 
And don't forget that both `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` allow you to construct result nodes in a different namespace using the `namespace` attribute.

There is `*:foo` to select or match `foo` elements in any namespace.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to see if that is my best option. Usually I use XSLT 1.0, but clearly your proposal does not fit there. Do you know if the xsl:attribute construct can be used for declaring namespaces?

Comment: @Birdie, you use Saxon but XSLT 1? Saxon 9 supports XSLT 2 or, since 9.8, XSLT 3. As for `xsl:attribute`, namespace declarations are not considered attributes in the XSLT data model but of course you can create elements in a certain namespaces with both literal result elements (e.g. `<p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</p>`) or `xsl:element` (`<xsl:element name="p" namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</xsl:element>`) and you can use create attributes in a certain namespace both literally or with `xsl:attribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Easily done in XSLT 2.0 using `xsl:namespace`.

If you really need to do it in XSLT 1.0 (why?), there's a tortuous workaround:

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:element name="{$prefix}:dummy" namespace="{$uri}"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($temp//*/namespace::*)"/>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. Can you give an example using xsl:namespace for the clarity? I am not sure how its syntax goes.

Comment: There are a couple of examples in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-namespace